# Use spark_csv inside Jupyter and using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

My ultimate goal is to use Jupyter together with Python for data analysis using Spark. The current hurdle I face is loading the external `spark_csv` library. I am using Mac OS and Anaconda as the Python distribution.

In particular, the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local', 'pyspark')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('file.csv')
df.show()
```

when invoked from Jupyter yields:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
```

Here are more details:

### Setting Spark together with Jupyter

I managed to set up Spark/PySpark in Jupyter/IPython (using Python 3.x).

### System initial setting

On my OS X I installed Python using Anaconda. The default version of Python I have currently installed is 3.4.4 (Anaconda 2.4.0). Note, that I also have installed also 2.x version of Python using `conda create -n python2 python=2.7`.

### Installing Spark

This is actually the simplest step; download the latest binaries into `~/Applications` or some other directory of your choice. Next, untar the archive `tar -xzf spark-X.Y.Z-bin-hadoopX.Y.tgz`.
For easy access to Spark create a symbolic link to the Spark:

```
ln -s ~/Applications/spark-X.Y.Z-bin-hadoopX.Y ~/Applications/spark
```

Lastly, add the Spark symbolic link to the PATH:

```
export SPARK_HOME=~/Applications/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You can now run Spark/PySpark locally: simply invoke `spark-shell` or `pyspark`.

### Setting Jupyter

In order to use Spark from within a Jupyter notebook, prepand the following to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARKHOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$SPARKHOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```

Further details can be found [here](https://github.com/drorata/Jupyter-Spark-Python-setup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your configuration is correct all you have to do is to make `spark-csv` jar available to your program. There are a few ways you can achieve this:

- manually download required jars including  [`spark-csv`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-csv_2.10/1.3.0/spark-csv_2.10-1.3.0.jar) and csv parser (for example [`org.apache.commons.commons-csv`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.2)) and put them somewhere on the `CLASSPATH`.
- using `--packages` option (use Scala version which has been used to build Spark. Pre-built versions use 2.10):

  - using `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environmental variable:

    ```
    export PACKAGES="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0"
    export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages ${PACKAGES} pyspark-shell"
    ```
  - adding Gradle string to `spark.jars.packages` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

    ```
    spark.jars.packages    com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0
    ```

Comment: I used the `--packages` options. It seems like the addition to `spark-defaults.conf` is crucial. Without it, as suggested by @DamianWilbur it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following procedure on your Mac--

1. vi to ~/.bash_profile (~/.zshrc if you're on that train)
2. Paste the following entry (be sure to specify your desired version of spark-csv)--

`export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0 $PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"`

From there, run 'ipython notebook' and test with something like this--

```
import pyspark as ps
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = ps.SparkContext()

input_csv = 'file:////PATH_TO_CSV_ON_LOCAL_FILESYSTEM'

df=sqlContext.read.load(input_csv,format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')

df.dtypes  # Returns the csv's schema breakdown with types
```